# auth.log being filled by pointless logs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logging

I have written a c++ app that reads from a USB port.  I also have a php daemon that calls this app every minute of every day.  For each call, the following log gets written to the auth.log file:

```
Jan 23 07:09:09 [server-name] sudo:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=[path-to-app] ; USER=root ; COMMAND=[path-to-app]/relaymon r
Jan 23 07:09:09 [server-name] sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jan 23 07:09:09 [server-name] sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

[path-to-app] replaces the real path in the log
[server-name] replaces the true server name in the log

Can anyone tell me how I can configure the system to not generate these log entries please?

Comment: You think logging root logins is pointless?

Comment: sudo logging is NOT pointless!

Comment: no what is pointless is logging something that is automated and I know is running every time the daemon runs.  hence the background in the question.  I dont think at any stage I said I wanted to stop logging in general, just this command running from a daemon

Comment: OP just wants to filter out these sudo entries. He is not debating whether they are pointless or not.

Comment: yes Chetan, correct, sorry if my question wasnt specific enough to say that.  just wanted to stop a log being generated for this command running from within the daemon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of disabling the logging, I would change your program to not require being run as root (might need to change device permissions) and change your PHP app to not call it with `sudo`.

Comment: yes I think I know where the problem is, the daemon runs as root anyway so there is no need for the command to contain "sudo".  I will change the daemon and restart it to see if this works

Answer (score 2):

Personally anytime sudo is executed, I WANT to be informed and a log entry made.  Thus I am confused and concerned about your choice and decision to attempt to suppress these entries.

However, (not recommended) you could configure syslog not to store these entries.

Comment: ah ok so its because the command contains sudo that the log is being generated?  as the daemons run as root anyway, if i remove the sudo command from the line of code the logging should stop?

Comment: yep, this is the case.

Comment: ok, daemon updated and restarted and it works!  thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  Oh and thank you for reading the question, unlike some others that are quick to hit the keyboard before the brain engages

Answer (score 0):

You can use `visudo` and add this line to disable logging:

`Defaults  !syslog`

This will disable ALL logging for all users.

There are examples/options in the sudoers man page to configure logging.

For example:

`Defaults:php_user !syslog`

should disable logging for only the `php_user` user.