# Is there any way to force sudo to not log actions from a specific user?

Tags: linux, logging, sudo

All of the servers in my network are running a Zabbix agent for monitoring, and some of the additional items I've added to them require the use of `sudo` to execute.
Normally this isn't *that* bad, but for one in particular, this results in about 75 lines *every minute* in the journal relating to it's usual data gathering.

Is there any way to specifically tell `sudo` to **not log anything** for a particular user?

I tried adding

```
Defaults:zabbix logfile=/dev/null
```

to my `sudoers` file, which stopped the `session opened` and `session closed` log lines, but isn't stopping this mess:

```
sudo[12424]:   zabbix : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=...
sudo[12433]:   zabbix : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=...
sudo[12435]:   zabbix : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=...
sudo[12437]:   zabbix : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=...
sudo[12449]:   zabbix : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=...
sudo[12459]:   zabbix : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=...
sudo[12465]:   zabbix : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=...
sudo[12467]:   zabbix : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=...
```

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/471524/auth-log-being-filled-by-pointless-logs

Comment: Try `Defaults:zabbix !syslog`

Comment: @fpmurphy Didn't know that was an option... seems to have done it though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `visudo`, you can add this line to your syslog configuration to disable all logging for user `zabbix`:

```
Defaults: zabbix  !syslog
```

Comment: Just a note, that I almost forgot: Shortly after doing this, Zabbix's sessions were hanging and tying up a lot of resources. It turns out that with `!syslog`, a `sudo` attempt would hang, indefinitely. A probably incorrect workaround I found was to just drop the lines before recording them using an `rsyslog` action.